# Ocultar celdas en VBA excel sin que se borre su formula

Tags: excel, vba

Saludos tengo un problema con VBA excel tengo el siguiente codigo que es para ocultar celdas en un rango y otro para volver a su lugar pero cuando vuelve a su lugar las formulas que tenia en las celdas se borran aparecen vacias.

Este es el codigo para ocultar las celdas

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

Rows("11:34").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
Range("11:11,13:13,15:15,17:17,19:19,21:21,23:23,25:25,27:27,29:29,31:31").Select
   
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True

Range("A5:Q34").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A5:Q34").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False

End Sub
```

Este es el codigo para volver a mostrar las celdas

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

Rows("10:34").Select
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = False
ActiveWindow.SmallScroll Down:=13

End Sub
```

En las celdas que se ocultan tengo formulas las cuales uso pero cuando se ocultan y se restauran las formulas se borran.
Alguna idea de como se puede evitar que se borren las celdas, se agradeceria mucho.

Answer (score 2):

Claro, estás sobreescribiendo.

Mira, esta parte de código oculta celdas:

```
Range("11:11,13:13,15:15,17:17,19:19,21:21,23:23,25:25,27:27,29:29,31:31").Select
   
Selection.EntireRow.Hidden = True
```

Si te fijas, ocultas todas las filas impares desde la fila 11 a la 31. Pero luego más tarde haces lo siguiente:

```
Range("A5:Q34").Select
Selection.Copy
Range("A5:Q34").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Aquí el código coge el rango de celdas A5:Q34 **y copia pega encima como valores** lo que elimina las fórmulas. Dentro del rango A5:Q34 están justo las filas que has ocultado. Por eso pierdes las fórmulas. Tienes que excluir las filas ocultas.

La opción más fácil que veo es algo así:

```
Range("11:11,13:13,15:15,17:17,19:19,21:21,23:23,25:25,27:27,29:29,31:31").EntireRow.Hidden = True 'ocultamos


For i = 5 To 34 Step 1
    'si la fila NO está oculta, pegamos valores
    If Range("A" & i).EntireRow.Hidden = False Then Range("A" & i & ":Q" & i) = Range("A" & i & ":Q" & i).Value
Next i
```

Un bucle que mire si la fila está oculta o no: si **no** lo está, entonces pega valores.

Comment: Gracias si recien me di cuenta del error, ya lo aplico muchas gracias por la ayuda.